# Symfony 4 - Como salvar imagens com o FormBuilder (FileType) em Base64 no Banco de Dados(MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, base64, symfony, symfony4

Olá, estou tentando fazer um formulário onde o usuário apenas insere uma imagem. Na teoria, a imagem deveria ser armazenada como um arquivo Blob (Base64) no Banco de Dados, porém, o Symfony está armazenando "tmp/php/*valor aleatório*" no campo "foto" da tabela credencial. Não sei se está faltando algo, pois com um `return $this->json($credencial->getFoto())`, o retornado é realmente uma string Base64.

Credencial:

```
class Credencial {
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(name="foto", type="blob")
    */
    protected $foto;

    public getFoto() {
        return $this->foto();
    }

    public setFoto($foto) {
        $this->foto = $foto;
    }
}
```

CredencialType:

```
class CredencialType extends AbstractType {
    protected $router;

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router) {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
        ->add('foto', FileType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Foto',
            'required' => false
        ))->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
            'label' => 'SALVAR',
            'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-info']
        ));
    }
}
```

Rota do CredencialController de adição de novas credenciais:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/credencial/add", name="credencial_add")
 * @Template()
 */
public function add(Request $request) {
    $credencial = new Credencial();
    $form = $this->createForm(CredencialType::class, $credencial);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($credencial);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('credencial_add');
    }

    return ['form' => $form->createView()];
}
```

Toda ajuda será bem-vinda, muito obrigado desde já!

Comment: Quando o flush() é executado o que aparece no /var/log/dev.log? aparece algum erro ou diz foi salvo certo?

Comment: Ao adicionar uma nova credencial, o var/log/dev.log não recebe nenhuma nova linha. O que acontece é que está salvando, porém o campo "foto" no banco de dados ao invés de receber a string com a imagem em base64, recebe algo como "tmp/php*algo aleatório*"

Comment: Fiz novamente o teste, campo "foto" no Banco de Dados = "/tmp/phpr2bYka", não sei se precisa fazer alguma conversão para base64, mas o que acho estranho é o fato de retornar em base64, mas não salvar, também em base64 no persist

Comment: Ok, tava dando uma olhada na [documentação](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/file.html), e pelo que eu vi o que ta sendo guardado na $credential->foto é uma instância do UploadedFile, então talvez se tu tenta bota isso antes de da o persist: "$credential->setFoto($form['foto']->getData());"

Comment: Olá amigo(a)! Parece que não funcionou "$credential->setFoto($form['foto']->getData());" :(, ainda continua salvando "tmp/phpBlabla"

Comment: O que acho estranho é "return $this->json($form["foto"]->getData());" estar retornando: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/.........................................................." como se fosse uma string com os dados em base64

Comment: Olá!!! acabei de realizar um teste com "$credencial->setFoto(file_get_contents($form["foto"]->getData()));" e funcionou perfeitamente! Salvou no banco de dados como base64, caramba, muito obrigado, você me deu as palavras chaves pra pesquisar mais sobre o problema!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente o que `$form["foto"]` possui é uma instância de UploadedFile, como [fajuchem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/110834/fajuchem) disse. o `return $this->json($form["foto"]->getData());` realizava a conversão automaticamente para string, por isso retornava a string base64 da imagem, e para salvar no Banco de Dados é necessário utilizar `file_get_contents`, que lê o conteúdo de um arquivo e recebe como parâmetro o diretório desse arquivo, que a propósito, era o que o `$form["foto"]` possuia e estava o armazenando no BD.